# Is there a way to change fonts and colors for the C# Interactive window in the Roslyn CTP?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, development-environment, roslyn

It seems to have partially inherited fonts and colors from my current settings, which has made it pretty ugly right now. I looked in fonts and colors but there is no settings for C# Interactive.

[image: ewwwww]
[image: tools & options]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I work for Microsoft on the Roslyn team.

We have not done the polish work to create the logical and correct fonts and colors for the C# Interactive Window yet. In this case, the black text in your screenshot should using Text Editor->Plain Text, but it's not. Instead, it's using "Text Editor->Interactive Console - Black". If you change "Text Editor->Interactive Console - Black" to match your "Text Editor->Plain Text" setting, it should look much better.

Comment: thanks, i figured it was due to being a ctp that these details were fully baked in.

Comment: Can't find the Text Editor-> Interactive Console settings in VS 2012 RC with Roslyn June 2012 CTP. Is it because I only upgrade directly from VS 2012 Beta instead of clean installing it?

Answer (score 1):

In the June 2012 CTP you can set the C# Interactive Window output fonts & colors using the following under "Text Editor":

```
Roslyn - Interactive Window Error Output
Roslyn - Interactive Window Output
```

Input fonts & colors are governed by the normal text editor settings.