# Change fonts and colors for C# Interactive Window in Visual Studio 2012 RC with Roslyn June 2012 CTP

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, roslyn

The default setting works well for Light Theme, but on dark setting, the default message text stay black (actually the error message text color also stay, but it's red, so it's ok). Basically it looks exactly like in the related question, but in this case I'm using VS 2012.

> **Related**
>   [Is there a way to change fonts and colors for the C# Interactive window in the Roslyn CTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155616/is-there-a-way-to-change-fonts-and-colors-for-the-c-sharp-interactive-window-in/)

Answer (score 2):

We have not done any work to support the dark theme automatically yet, though we do plan to.

In the meantime, there should be entries in Tools/Options/Environment/Fonts and Colors for all of our items, though the names of several have changed since the October CTP.

Comment: What are the new names? I found Roslyn, but changing them don't do anything to the interactive window, and none named "interactive window" or such

Comment: I had this issue as well, and I had to go through and test every single font setting, since the one used was something like "default text"... IE the C# Interactive window does not use the fonts named Roslyn..... maybe I should have filed it as a bug =P

Answer (score 2):

In the June 2012 CTP you can set the C# Interactive Window output fonts & colors using the following under "Text Editor":

```
Roslyn - Interactive Window Error Output
Roslyn - Interactive Window Output
```

Input fonts & colors are governed by the normal text editor settings.

Comment: Nope. I would have found it if it's there. The first settings named Roslyn is Roslyn - Operator. I'll try reinstalling my VS

Comment: Did you upgrade your RC directly from Beta or by clean installing it?

Comment: I got a new PC in the meantime, so it was a very clean install.

Comment: Odd, even my friend who installed VS 2010, uninstalled, then install RC still only get Roslyn - Operator as the first settings. So in your RC installation, there's an item named Roslyn - Interactive ... and later Roslyn - Operator few item below it right?

Comment: Right - the first two are the ones I listed above, following by "Roslyn - Operator" (and a large number after that).

Comment: Ok thank you. So it's indeed the problem in me and my friend OS. Was afraid if I somehow missed scanning the items.