# How to change fonts in C# Interactive in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, c#-interactive

How do I change fonts in the C# Interactive window in Visual Studio 2015?

Particularly, I'd like to change the font size, but also, if possible, the colours.

I'm aware of [Is there a way to change fonts and colors for the C# Interactive window in the Roslyn CTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8155616/126014) and [Change fonts and colors for C# Interactive Window in Visual Studio 2012 RC with Roslyn June 2012 CTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10990732/126014), but they both refer to CTPs, and the answers given there don't seem to apply to Visual Studio 2015.

I'm asking specifically about Visual Studio 2015, not Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: It uses the same font, size and colors as the text editor.  It only has a setting for the color of error messages.  Pretty sane choice, you are typing C# code in that window.  You'd have to file a feature request to get them to change it, I have no idea how you could make that sound convincing.  Good luck.

Comment: @HansPassant So it does! Thank you. If you write that comment as an answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Comment: @HansPassant BTW, the reason I asked is that *F# Interactive* has its own settings in Visual Studio, so I just assumed that it'd work the same way for *C# Interactive*...

Comment: I'll pass, SO users like happy answers.  No reason why you couldn't just answer it yourself.

Comment: @HansPassant Fair enough, but to be clear, I'm happy enough with the answer. I need to show a demo with C# interactive, and wanted to make sure that the code I'd be writing would be big enough for all to see. Your answer sufficiently addresses that problem.